# Show that the set of all $n \times n$ orthogonal matrices, $O(n)$, is a compact subset of $\mbox{GL} (n,\mathbb R)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, orthogonal-matrices

I have only concept in topology, metric space, and functional analysis. How do I tackle this? Also  I want to know that is the set connected?

Comment: Please add the source if you have collected it from some question paper of entrance examination. Most probably it is a question of NBHM but I have forgotten the year.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hints:

- $\mathcal O(n)$ is the continuous inverse image of a closed set…
- There exists a rather obvious bound for every element in $\mathcal O(n)$ and thus this set is bounded…

Now Heine-Borel and we're done.

**Added:** Thanks to the comments by Berci I think some confusion may happen here, since the orthogonal group is *not* the inverse image of $\,\{1,-1\}\,$ under the determinant map in the whole $\,GL(n,\Bbb R)\,$ (as there are matrices with determinant $\,\pm 1\,$ which are not orthogonal, of course).

So let us try the following approach: the map $\,T:GL(n,\Bbb R)\to GL(n,\Bbb R)\,$ defined by $\,T(A):=AA^t\,$ is continuous since every entry in the matrix $\,AA^t\,$ is a polynomial on the entries of $\,A\,$ ,and now we can see that

$$\mathcal O(n)=T^{-1}(\{I\})$$

and, of course, $\,\{I\}\,$ is a closed set, so $\,\mathcal O(n)\,$ is closed.

Comment: Antonio,Is  the mapping $ A\mapsto AA^t $. I can not understand why the set is bounded.can you explain me plz?

Comment: If $A\in O(n)$ then $\|A\|=1$.

Comment: @AnindyaGhatak: If $\,A=(a_{ij})\in\mathcal O(n)\,$ , then$$AA^t=1\implies \sum_{k=1}^na_{ik}^2=1\;,\;\;\forall\;i=1,2,\ldots,n$$

Comment: Oh, and the continuous map I was talking about is the determinant map: $$\det:GL(n,\Bbb R)\to\Bbb R$$Of course, the set $\,\{-1,1\}\,$ is closed in $\,\Bbb R\,$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio ,thanks

Comment: Anytime,@AnindyaGhatak....

Comment: But.. $O(n)\ne\det^{-1}(\{-1,1\})$, it's rather something like $SL(n)$.

Comment: First @Berci, I think you may have meant $\,SO(n)\,$ , and second $$\mathcal O(n)=\det^{-1}\{-1,1\}\;,\;\;SO(n)=\det^{-1}\{1\}\,$$unless, as many other times, I misunderstood something here.

Comment: For example $\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}$ has determinant $1$, though it's not orthogonal. By definition, $SL(n)=\det^{-1}(1)$.

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion: sorry. Of course, it must be that $\,A^t=A^{-1}\,$, or the matrix's rows are orthogonal vector in $\,\Bbb R^n\,$ . *There* is where all happens.

Comment: Thanks @Berci for noting that. I added some stuff to my answer that I hope will clean this mess.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you can say more:

Using the canonical action of $SO(n)$ on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, you can show that $SO(n)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. But you have the exact sequence $1 \to SO(n) \to O(n) \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 1$, so $[O(n):SO(n)]=2$ and $O(n)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \coprod \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.