# How to prove that the map $f: M_n(\Bbb R) \to M_n(\Bbb R)$ defined by $A \mapsto AA^t$ is continuous?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof

This map has appeared several times on this site such as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18653/compactness-of-the-set-of-n-times-n-orthogonal-matrices), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447102/orthogonal-matrices-form-a-compact-set?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346503/show-that-the-set-of-all-orthogonal-matrix-of-order-n-on-is-a-compact-sub). I thought of writing out a proof for the continuity of this map. Identify $M_n(\Bbb R)$ with $\Bbb R^{n^2}$.

I tried using sequential way to prove the continuity here.

So let $X_n$ be a converging sequence in $M_n(\Bbb R)$ and $||\cdot||$ be max-norm norm on $M_n(\Bbb R)$ i.e. $||A||=\max {(a_{ij})}.$ Then $\forall \; \delta \gt 0 \; \exists N \in \Bbb N$ such that $||X_n - X|| \lt \delta \; \forall \; n \ge N.$ This also means that $\forall \; \delta \gt 0 \; \exists N \in \Bbb N$ such that $||X_n^t - X^t|| \lt \delta \; \forall \; n \ge N.$

Consider $||f(X_n)-f(X)||=||X_n X_n^t-XX^t||=||X_n X_n^t - XX^t + X_nX^t - X_n X^t|| \le ||X_n X_n^t - X_n X^t||+
||X_nX^t-XX^t||= ||X_n(X_n^t-X^t)||+||X^t(X_n-X)||.$

But I am stuck at the last step. What can I do from here?

Also I am intereseted in knowing other ways to show this.

**EDIT :** I have found that as per the norm that I have used, $||AB|| \not \le ||A||||B||.$ Take $$A = \left[ \begin{matrix}
        1 & 2 \\
        3 & 4 \\
       \end{matrix}\right]$$ and $$B = \left[ \begin{matrix}
        4 & 5 \\
        6 & 7 \\
       \end{matrix}\right].$$ So my way will not work.

This is because I was thinking whether $||X_n(X_n^t-X^t)|| \le ||X_n||||X_n^t-X^t||$ could be done. But my purpose is defeated.

Comment: I would just show that it is polynomial in the entries.  This suffices for product-space reasons.

Comment: Okay. What do you mean by product-space reasons?

Comment: A map to a product (like $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$) is continuous if and only if it is continuous in each coordinate (so, entry).

Comment: @Randall A well-known result from calculus which I forgot to think about. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately your norm $||A||=\max {|a_{ij}|}$ is not submultiplikative. Since all norms on $M_n(\Bbb R)$ are equivalent, we can choose a norm which is submultiplikative.
Let $ ||⋅|| $ such a norm.

Then we have

$||X_n(X_n^t-X^t)||+||X^t(X_n-X)|| \le ||X_n|| \cdot||X_n^t-X^t||+||X^t|| \cdot ||X_n-X||$.

Can you take it from here ? Observe that $(||X_n||)$  is bounded.

Comment: Okay. I would like to think about a different norm for a while. Thanks! and yes ,as $||X_n||$ is convergent so it is bounded.

Comment: An advantage of this proof is: it will also work for operators on  infinite-dimensional normed spaces.

Comment: I used this norm : $||A||=\sup \{||Ax|| : ||x||=1\}$. It is sub-multiplicative! As $||X_n||$ bounded, so it's essentially sequence of bounded linear operators. Also I found that what I am showing is just "jointly continuous" property under multiplication operation.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for this generalized comment! +1

Answer (score 6):

Here's a tricky solution. Consider a function

$$F:\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})\otimes \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$$
$$F(A\otimes B)=AB^{t}$$

where $\otimes$ stands for the tensor product of vector spaces. This function is linear, hence continuous.

Now consider

$$G:\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})\otimes \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$$
$$G(A)=A\otimes A$$

This function although not linear is also continuous:

*Proof.* Fix a basis $\{e_1,\ldots, e_m\}$ for $\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$. It follows that

$$G(v)=G\big(\sum\lambda_i e_i\big)=\sum\lambda_i e_i\otimes \sum\lambda_i e_i=\sum_{i, j}\lambda_i\lambda_j (e_i\otimes e_j)$$

Define $\pi_{i,j}:\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})\otimes \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ to be $(i,j)$ projection, i.e. $\pi_{i,j}(\lambda e_i\otimes e_j)=\lambda$ and $0$ elsewehere. It follows that

$$\pi_{i,j}\circ G:\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$$
$$\pi_{i,j}\circ G\big(\sum\lambda_k e_k\big)=\lambda_i\lambda_j$$
In other words $\pi_{i,j}\circ G$ is just a multiplication of two chosen coordinates. This is continuous because the multiplication is. Hence by the definition of product topology $G$ is continuous. $\Box$

Now it is easy to see that $f=F\circ G$ is continuous.

Comment: I am upvoting this answer because it uses something different that I am not aware of. Once I learn tensor products, I will come back to this answer. +1

Comment: @GEdgar who says it is superior? What does it even mean?

Comment: Is it more than just a disguised way of saying, "the entries are polynomials".

Comment: @GEdgar with a proof. Im not sure what is the point od your comments.

Comment: @freakish there are many ways to topologize the tensor product of two topological spaces. You should make explicit which one you are using. If you define it to be minimal so that $V \times W \to V\otimes W$ is continuous, then proof is overkill since the diagonal map is always continuous, and so $G$ can be identified with the composition of two continuous functions.

Comment: @AndresMejia Obviously any norm topology (tensor product is finite dimensional) so that multiplication is continuous. Im not sure if they coincide.