# why $f(A)$ is continuous?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

**The  subset  of all orthogonal  matrices is compact** .

Proof is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/346507/557708)

**My confusion**: we  define  $f : GLn(\mathbb{R}) \to GLn(\mathbb{R})$ by  $f(A) =AA^T$

Here  why $f(A)$ is continious?

**My thinking** :Here  $f(A)$ is not a polynomial, so $f(A)$  will  not continuous

If we take  $A= (a_{ij}$)  then  $$AA^T=I=\begin{pmatrix} a_{11}^2 +...+a_{1n}^2 & 0 & .... & 0 \\ 0 & a_{21}^2 +...+a_{2n}^2 & .... & 0  \\ ... & .... & ... & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & ... & a_{n1}^2 +...+a_{nn}^2\end{pmatrix}$$

$\implies  \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{ik}^2=1$  for all $i=1,2,.....$

But in the proof it is written that $f(A)$ is continuous

I'm  not getting that why $f(A)$ is continuous?

Comment: ...which site ?

Comment: @Physor stack exchange(MSE)

Comment: Which proof are you referring to? Please add a link.

Comment: @MartinR i edited see the link

Comment: I don't see where the orthogonal matrecies come into play after the second line, do mean that you take an orthogonal $A$ from $GLn(\mathbb R)$ ?, please write all the details

Comment: Isn't that explained in the referenced  answer? *“... is continuous since every entry in the matrix $AA^t$ is a polynomial on the entries of $A$”*

Comment: @MartinR  Actually  i didn't understand  how each entry of $AA^T$ is a polynomial in the entries of $A$, because  here $a_{11}^2 +...+a_{1n}^2$ is not a polynomial

Comment: It is a polynomial in the variables $a_{11}, \ldots, a_{1n}$.

Comment: okk got it now thanks u @MartinR

Comment: @Physor i edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the contrary: each entry of $f(A)$ is a polynomial in the entries of $A$, and so it is continuous.

Comment: Here $a_{11}^2 +...+a_{1n}^2$ is not a polynomial ? im not getting that how each entry of $f(A)$ is a polynomial in the entries of $A$? Can you elaborate more

Comment: $a_{11}^2 + \ldots + a_{1n}^2$ is a [polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial#Definition) in the variables $a_{11}, \ldots, a_{1n}$.  That is, it is an expression built from those variables and constants by addition, multiplication and non-negative integer powers.